# Laravel - LoginController::authenticated() not fired at each login?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to log the IP address and login timestamps when users log into our system, and in order to do so I have overriden the authenticated() method of the LoginController :

```php
function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
      $user->update([
        'last_login_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'last_ip' => $request->getClientIp()
      ]);
    }
```

The strange thing is that I can see in the database that the last login from some users are several days ago, whether I know for a fact that they performed actions on the website today (while being logged-in), as shown by other logs..

Is there a possibility that authenticated() is not being fired, depending on how the user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

`authenticated()` method fires always when user logs in.
Possible Problems:

- You have not added `last_login_at` and `last_ip` in a fillable property in your User Model
- Users Has checked remember button. In this case `authenticated()` method does not fires

Comment: Thanks.. no luck here though.. The attributes are fillable (they do get filled sometimes, but not everytime it seems) - and "remember me" is disabled on my system

Answer (score 0):

It seems okay only thing you missed maybe the return statement? In my application I have similar functionality and working fine try below -

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {

    $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->last_ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your system is set-up but you can always try listening for the `Login` event which is fired whenever a user logs in via any means. This includes getting authenticated after the session is expired and the user is automatically logged in via the "remember me" cookie.

In your `EventServiceProvider` you can add:

```
\Event::listen(\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class, function ($event) {
      $event->user->update([
         'last_login_at' => Carbon::now(),
         'last_ip' => request()->getClientIp()
     ]);
});
```

Note if your session does not actually expire or lasts a very long time users might stay logged in for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Socialite to allow social logins via Facebook, Google, etc. then those will not fire the authenticated event.  As another user noted, it also will not fire when the user has checked the remember button.